# Where are PDFs stored from ddjvu or djvu2pdf?

Tags: pdf, djvu

I cannot locate the directory after making the conversion from djvu to pdf when using either `ddjvu` or djvu2pdf`. Unless  specify a specific path, i.e.

```
ddjvu -format=pdf "/Users/x/Downloads/Ramanujan/Continued Fractions/Continued fractions (Carl D. Olds, A. Rockett, P. Szusze) (Z-Library).djvu" /Users/x/Downloads/Continued_Fractions.pdf
```

Then its stored in my Downloads, but where does it naturally store the pdfs?

Answer (score 1):

From the [DDJVu Manual](https://djvu.sourceforge.net/doc/man/ddjvu.html)

> Decode the DjVu file djvufile, produces the image file outputfile.

> The DjVu data is read from the standard input when argument djvufile is not specified or when it is equal to a single dash. Similarly, the output data is written to the standard output when argument outputfile is not specified or equal to a single dash. However a **valid output file name is always required when producing a TIFF or PDF file**.

Hence it stores the PDF wherever you want it to be saved.

Thus you specified `/Downloads/Continued_Fractions.pdf` as the output location and filename.

While running you may see a temporary name

```
DjVuLibre-3.5.28>ddjvu -format=pdf continued-fractions.djvu %cd%\continued-fractions.pdf

Dir c*.*
Directory of \Users\...\Downloads\DjVuLibre-3.5.28

2024-03-28  13:56        15,846,978 continued-fractions.djvu
2024-03-28  14:22        53,500,994 continued-fractions.pdf.a07320


Later ...
2024-03-28  14:24       213,986,768 continued-fractions.pdf.a07320
           2 File(s)    229,833,746 bytes
Later ...
2024-03-28  14:28       514,777,832 continued-fractions.pdf.a07320
Later ...
2024-03-28  14:29       643,433,147 continued-fractions.pdf.a07320
Yawn ...
2024-03-28  14:31       780,188,774 continued-fractions.pdf.a07320
ZZzzz ....
2024-03-28  14:33       940,027,112 continued-fractions.pdf.a07320

Finally ...
2024-03-28  13:56        15,846,978 continued-fractions.djvu
2024-03-28  14:36     1,036,186,348 continued-fractions.pdf
```